Is it considered vulgar to use "massive" to describe female breast size?
I’m currently working on the outlines for my main characters, and my female lead has very specific features and measurements. Breast size and buttocks shape and size has always been the most difficult for me to describe in a tasteful manner. With my main character having size HH cups I cannot think of any other way to describe them as “amply massive heavy slopes.”
The story will have mature content and is in the dark-fantasy romance genre.

Just out of curiosity, what in the plot needs such specific bodily features?

Perhaps try "voluptuous" on for size.

@Graham I think OP answered this by specifying that the story "will have mature content and is in the dark-fantasy romance genre". To me that implies lots of explicit sexual scenes that must naturally contain vivid descriptions of body parts and how they might be sexually employed.

"Well-endowed" is a decent alternative descriptor.

Is the question about the word "massive" (which is borderline, but you could make an argument about it being appropriate), or the phrase "amply massive heavy slopes" (which very much approaches the "holy bazongas" territory, in addition to being 50 percent redundant)?

I wouldn't say the use of massive here is vulgar, but it is a very sexualized description. If that is the viewpoint that you want your readers to have on your characters, then that is appropriate; if not, not.
Generally, the more detailed your descriptions of the bodies of your characters are, the more sexualized they become. The less sexual you want your story to be, the less you should mention their primary or secondary sexual organs.
That seems a bit counter-intuitive, especially when it comes to women's breasts, since women often dress in a manner that presents that part of their bodies very prominently, but it is an unspoken convention in Western cultures to act as if women's breasts didn't exist. Acknowledging them with your gaze or with words or actions is considered inappropriate or even transgressive. This is reflected in literature where the exact shape of women's breasts is usually hidden behind words such as beautiful or attractive that leave the exact shape of that beauty and attractiveness unspecified. The more you make your readers stare at your female character's chests, the more your story verges into erotica.
If you want to bring your character's sexual corporeality to your readers attention, there are many words that you can use, depending on the exact meaning that you are after. Massive has a connotation of a great weight, while generous emphasizes the volume. You could browse a thesaurus and collect synonyms for huge and then look up their meanings and usages in a dictionary to find the most fitting word for the meaning you are after.
Sometimes it is better, though, not to try to express that meaning through adjectives alone and instead describe the emotions or thoughts that some object or event elicits in one of your characters. For example, you could describe how a person meeting the woman with the ample bosom is overcome with the urge to bury their face in her chest and cry with relief.

I wouldn't say the use of massive here is vulgar.  Yeah, it's absolutely vulgar, since the definition is "lacking in cultivation, perception, or taste".  That's because the Latin root of vulgar is "common people, the masses"; Bud-swilling good ole boys who think those hooters are massive.

@RonJohn I'm not clear on what point you're trying to make. Humankind is vulgar?

@Mentalist I think they're trying to make the point that "vulgar" in linguistics has a slightly different meaning than in common usage: while most people would conflate "vulgar" with "gross", "lacking taste" etc., for linguists saying that a word is "vulgar" just means that it's used mostly by common and, especially, uneducated people (cf. vulgate).

@walen "common and uneducated people" are pretty much by definition "lacking (refined) taste".  That's why they're drinking Budweiser and Franzia instead of Weihenstephaner and Chateau Margaux.

@Mentalist I stand corrected: they were definitely not trying to make that point; they just think that people who drink Budweiser are peasants. The point I described is still true, nonetheless — just not the one this cultivated individual was making.

Rather than a neutral narrator judging and reporting on her breast size, let the characters do it. She can admire herself and think about how great it is to be well endowed. She can choose clothes that show off this bust of hers. Or she can wish she had a smaller bust and think about what that would be like. When we see her meet someone who is going to have a sex scene with her later, that character can be struck by the beautiful size of her breasts and think things like "those are the biggest I have ever seen" as well as "I can't wait to...". When they do have sex, whoever is manipulating them can marvel about not being able to hold them in one hand, or how soft and squishy they are, or whatever.
This comes back to showing and telling I think. Don't tell us anything is massive. Show us her dealing with massiveness, and other characters seeing and reacting to that massiveness.

No, "massive" is not vulgar, but it is also not specific or concrete as a descriptive word.

With my main character having size HH cups I cannot think of any other way to describe them as “amply massive heavy slopes.”

There are many non-vulgar and more specific ways to describe large breasts (or buttocks). They are the size of watermelons. Or basketballs, or beach balls. Or bigger than her head. Or 20 pounders. Two hands wide with fingers spread, with nipples the size of a man's palm.
"amply massive heavy slopes" does not produce a concrete image.
As a general rule of thumb when you are describing something visual, try to use concrete visual imagery, compare it to some thing that a typical person has actually seen, or at least has seen a picture or video of it -- e.g. the White House; we've all seen it in pictures and TV and movies, even though few of us have seen it in person.

Yeah, in this context, it's absolutely vulgar, since the definition is "lacking in cultivation, perception, or taste".  That's because the Latin root of vulgar is "common people, the masses"; Bud-swilling good ole boys who think those hooters are massive.

The colloquial meaning of "vulgar" does not rely on the origin of the word or precise definition. The common understanding is that "vulgar" implies overtly sexual. I don't believe "massive" in reference to breasts falls into the overtly sexual common understanding. And for a writer, the common understanding is absolutely something they should consider, because that is (by definition) the understanding their audience will most commonly have.

I quoted Merriam-Webster's first definition.  And vulgar language isn't necessarily sexual; it's just... crude or profane, or both.

I don't think it constitutes as vulgar. Unless you are using it to say something like, "Massive knockers." But you might want to add more descriptive words to give a clearer image of what you want your readers to envision. Don't go all Stephen King and spend several paragraphs to describe one thing but a couple more wouldn't hurt.

Describing women's breasts is considered vulgar.

@david Depends on context. Plastic surgeons have a whole technical vocabulary to describe them in a clinical context, none of which is vulgar. Alternatively, a husband (privately) waxing poetic to his wife about how beautiful her breasts are would likely also not be considered vulgar. -- It's less the describing per se which is vulgar, and more the fact that such descriptions tend to most often happen in the context of third parties crudely sexualizing women who have not really consented to be sexualized in such a fashion.
